# How to disable the creation of Thumbs.db file?

Tags: windows-xp

I am using Windows XP. Every time I delete a folder which contains Thumbs.db file, I get a message: Thumbs.db is a system file and then it allows me to delete it. Can I disable the creation of Thumbs.db file from the beginning itself?

Answer (score 1):

From Explorer window *Tools* menu *Folder Options* -> *View* -> **Do not cache thumbnails**